# Simple Mod_rewrite RegEx Debug

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Apologies for having to ask what seems like a very simple question, but I can't find an answer to this anywhere else.

I have the following .htaccess file with this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^project/(.*)/(.*)$ project.php?projectID=$1&pageID=$2
```

Designed to take a url in the format **domain.com/project/10/1** which will redirect and display page 1 of project 10, for example.

The option also exists to just view **domain.com/project/10/** without specifying a page number, and if missing it will default to page one.

The problem I have with the RegEx is that this defaulting behaviour requires the trailing slash for the projectID, otherwise it throws a 404.

How can I modify the RegEx so that it doesn't require (but *can* have optionally) the trailing slash at the end of the example '**domain.com/project/10/**' to successfully rewrite to '**project.php?projectID=$1**'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
^project/(.*)/?(.*)/?$
```

Question mark means that preceding symbol is optional

Comment: Thank you, however the problem with this solution is that if I now supply the trailing slash in 'project/10/' the rewritten page can no longer see $i, and it throws an error. Something I'm missing?

Comment: may be you can try ^project/(\d*)/?(\d*)/?$ , where (\d*) means any digit, because if you use (.*) regex captures everything to first group including slash and set it as parameter